# What is the correct way to add an element value to the end of a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Which one?

- `arr[arr.length+1] = value`
- `arr[arr.length] = value`
- `arr[arr.length-1] = value`
- `arr = arr + value`

Comment: Can't you just ... try it?

Comment: It seems you haven't made *any* effort of finding this out for yourself.

Comment: You can use `arr[arr.length] = value` as `array.length` always `+1` of the index of last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use

```
arr.push(value);
```

the value will be added to the end of the array

Comment: Which true in this options?

Comment: with your options it is `arr[arr.length] = value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second option.

```
arr[arr.length] = value
```

`Array` instance `.length` is 0-based, beginning at `0`. An array having three elements `[1,2,3]` will have `.length` `3`, though indexes `0` through `2` will be populated with values `1` through `3`. `arr[arr.length] = value` sets `value` at index `3`, where resulting `.length` will be `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to receive on return.

1. If you want to receive back the added element `array[array.length] = thingy // <- thingy`
2. If you want to receive back the length of the array `array.push(thingy) // <- array.length`
3. If you want to receive a copy of the array with the new element added at the last position `array.concat(thingy)` (care for array items to be added since they get spread i.e. `[].concat([1,2,3],[4,5,6]); // <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`)